# how to support virtual scrolling in tree table

Tags: primereact

I can see that primereact supports the virtualscroller but so far as I can see the TreeTable only supports traditional paging, is there any way to support infinite scroll in TreeTable?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently. It is an open enhancement issue on the GitHub project so I suggest you go subscribe and upvote the ticket.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1423